# Load an IDB file when debugging kernel to get the function names in IDA?

Tags: ida, debugging, kernel

I am debugging a windows kernel, and i have already analyzed some modules and have their IDB files.

Now is there anyway that i can somehow "map" these IDB files to their corresponding loaded location in kernel so i can get their function names? there are multiple IDB files that can get loaded anywhere in memory.

Comment: I would say that the straight forward approach is to have a single idb for different modules (which is allowed but a bit buggy, it does make duplicate modules sometimes instead of relocating all modules). Look for a plugin that does it.

Comment: @eyalkarni how can i convert all of them into one IDB?!

Comment: If no plugin, then probably would try extracting into idc script